# Need advice on the best way to filter text files based on a reference table

Tags: perl, oracle

I'm currently looking for a way to optimize a process that
takes a long time to run.

- There are about 270 text files to be filtered.
- Each file has about 70k~150k lines.
- The reference table has usually about **16m** records under Oracle 10g.
- The process is run every hour.
- There's a possibility that 9 instances of that process may be run almost
  simultaneaously.

What I currently do is spool the reference table into a file, copy that into
a hash, do the same with the text file, then do a hash key match up.
Any record on the text file found on the reference list will be discarded.

This gets repeated for all 270 files, however the spooling part is only done
once at the start.

However this approach consumes about 300mb~500mb of RAM, and with the
possibility of having multiple instances of that process running almost at
the same time, its nightmare to our server.

Any ideas how to do this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to only load DB data to the memory, and to process files like (sorry, that's a pseudocode, but you should get an idea and implement it in perl):

```
HashSet dbData = GetDataFromDB();
foreach(filename in filenames) {
    FileHandle handle = OpenRead(filename);
    FileHandle tmphandle = OpenWrite(filename + ".tmp");
    while(string line = handle.ReadLine()) {
        if(!dbData.Contains(line)) {
            tmphandle.Write(line);
        }
    }
    tmphandle.Flush();
    tmphandle.Close();
    handle.Close();
    Delete(filename);
    Rename(tmpfilename, filename);
}
```

This is going to take only about as much RAM as your reference table takes.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like something that could be done efficiently in the database (big anti-join).

You could use [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#BABDEJDH) to read the files and compare them directly to your reference table. You could use a wrapper function to select directly your file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_varchar AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_file(p_dir VARCHAR2, p_file VARCHAR2)
   RETURN tab_varchar
   PIPELINED IS
   l_file utl_file.file_type := utl_file.fopen(p_dir, p_file, 'r', 4000);
   l_line VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         utl_file.get_line(l_file, l_line);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN No_Data_Found THEN
            EXIT;
      END;
      PIPE ROW (l_line);
   END LOOP;
   utl_file.fclose(l_file);
   RETURN;
END;
/
```

This will allow you to select directly your data, for example this will return the content of the file `C:\tmp\a.txt`

```
create directory tmp_dir as 'C:\tmp\';

select column_value from table(select_file('TMP_DIR', 'a.txt'));
```

From here a single query should be ok for each file, something like:

```
INSERT INTO ref_table r
   (SELECT column_value
      FROM table(select_file(:dir, :file_name)
     WHERE column_value NOT IN (SELECT ref_value
                                  FROM ref_table
                                 WHERE ref_value IS NOT NULL)
       AND column_value IS NOT NULL);
```